# How can the global registrar be called from a contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I want to call what i would do in geth with registrar.owner(namevar) from a solidity contract.

Is this possible - and how?

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer..

Import the registrar.sol and initiate an object on the address.

Comment: Could you add some more details to your answer explaining how you solved it in detail? This might help future users running into the same issue.